# SQLITE - Round timestamp and count

Tags: sqlite

My SQLite database has a TIMESTAMP column, containing data like the following:

```
2020-03-12 21:18:44
2020-03-12 21:27:34
2020-03-12 21:37:25
2020-03-12 21:38:34
2020-03-12 21:39:44
2020-03-12 21:41:24
2020-03-12 21:43:41
2020-03-12 21:45:51
2020-03-12 21:49:47
2020-03-12 21:52:05
2020-03-12 22:00:30
2020-03-12 22:12:48
2020-03-12 22:17:37
2020-03-12 22:18:30
2020-03-12 22:20:01
2020-03-12 22:20:44
```

How can I process these timestamps to round them down to the nearest 15 minute interval (:00, :15, :30, :45) and then group them to get counts of rows matching that rounded time?

See example of desired output:

```
Timestamp (Rounded)   |   Count of Instances
--------------------------------------------
2020-03-12 21:15:00   |   2
2020-03-12 21:30:00   |   5
2020-03-12 21:45:00   |   3
```

Comment: Please read the sqlite tag wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info) to find out why and how to make an [mre].

Comment: Then spend some time to describe and show what you tried yourself, what your results are and how they differe from what you want.

Comment: I do not get what the second column in the desired result is. "2", "5", "3" are supposed to be what?

Comment: times counted and rounded down to 15 minutes to 21.15. In this case there were two values between 21.15 and 21.30,   five  values between 21.30 and 21.45 .....

Comment: I kind of guessed. Describing and explaining that in the question itself would however increase your chances. And don't forget to make a MRE. I don't want to spend effort on guessing and typing.

Comment: Your timestamps are stored as unix times, not strings? If so it's simple... But include a sample of your real data format in the question.

Comment: Hi Marek, is still something unclear to you? Can I explain something? Some time has passed and you seem unsatisfied wih the answer you got. But on the other hand you do not do anything to help with improving answers or making new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use the function [`substr()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and type casting to round the time and then aggregate:

```
select 
  substr(timecol, 1, length(timecol) - 5) ||
  substr('00' || ((cast(substr(timecol, -5) as int) / 15) * 15), -2) || ':00' period,
  count(*) counter
from tablename
group by period
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCT6a3D8skLhLaM69a29P1/3).
Or with the function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
select 
  strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:', timecol) ||
  substr('00' || ((cast(strftime('%M', timecol) as int) / 15) * 15), -2) || ':00' period,
  count(*) counter
from tablename
group by period
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCT6a3D8skLhLaM69a29P1/4).
Results:

```
| period              | counter |
| ------------------- | ------- |
| 2020-03-12 21:15:00 | 2       |
| 2020-03-12 21:30:00 | 5       |
| 2020-03-12 21:45:00 | 3       |
| 2020-03-12 22:00:00 | 2       |
| 2020-03-12 22:15:00 | 4       |
```

Comment: Yes, this version 

> Or with the function strftime():

is perfect for me
Thank You :)